# Get target and source ID while dragging and dropping

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

[Click to view fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tBaHd/5)I want to  get target span "id" but i am 
    not able to get .Below is the HTML of code
    I have tried a lot but i am able to get the
     source ID but not the dropped ID.Please let me know how can i get id's of draggable and dropped data

```
<div class="draggable_widget ui-sortable"><ul class="connectedSortable ui-sortable" id="T1">Team#0<li>1</li><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>2</li></ul></div>



    <span id="1">1<div style="height:30px;Width:40px;" id="1" class="droppable_widget ui-sortable"></div></span>



    $(function () {
                    $("#droppable").droppable({
                        start: function (event, ui) {

                        }

                    });

                    $(".draggable").draggable({
                        containment: 'document',
                        cursor: 'move',
                        revert: "invalid",


                    });
                    $(".droppable_widget,.draggable_widget").sortable({
                        connectWith: ".droppable_widget,.draggable_widget",
                        start: function (event, ui) {

                        },
                        stop: function (event, ui) {
                            var item = $(ui.item);
                            var to = item.parent().is(".droppable_widget");
                            var siblingsCount = item.siblings().size();
                            //alert($(ui.droppable).html());
                            if (to && siblingsCount > 0) {
                                alert("only one item allowed here");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                    });

                    $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
                        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
                    }).disableSelection;

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

First your HTML is not corrected, you must close your last "LI" element and the "UL" element.

Than if you see your code, the "SPAN" and the "DIV" inner this span, has the same ID and it's not allowed the same page.

To get ID's in the Sortable you want to this.

```
alert($(this).attr("id"));
```

As you can see in this JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tiagoajacobi/vXz39/

Comment: this is not the issue it is working..its the typo error from my end <ul> and <li> is properly closed and i need  to find id only i.e of span i think it dosn't matter that span and div has same id

Comment: But in which moment you want to get the ID? A updated the answer  to get the ID's in the drop event.

Comment: @user1474602, or do you want to get the ID in the "sortable" event?

Comment: i want the id of that element in which dragged item is dropped(i.e span id)

Comment: You suggested code is not working...it is not giving alert i.e inside drop function

Comment: i have tried the reciever function and right alert('hi'); it is also not coming there when item is dropped

Comment: My code just show how to get the ID from droppable element (who is the element you drop the draggable element)  and the draggable element (who is the element you are dragging)

Comment: yes i have tried this already thats why i have posted my problem  here below is the fiddle i have creted http://jsfiddle.net/tBaHd/5/  please check and let me know how to get dropped div id

Comment: @user1474602, now I understood, I've edited my answer, and posted the Fiddle working.

Comment: Fiddle code still not working giving undefined in alert

Answer (score 0):

The item that is being dragged has already been added to the destination, so you can look at its parent.

```
    var itemId = item.attr("id");
    var destId = item.parent().attr("id");
    var sourceId = event.target.id;

    alert(
        '"' + itemId + '" was dragged from "' + 
        sourceId + '" to "' + destId + '"');
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tBaHd/11/